# Will ToolBar work for API level>=14

Tags: android

The ToolBar class was added in android API 21. Does that mean that minimum API level required is 21. If that is the case how do I work in lower API's like 14. I am asking this question because Actionbar.TabListener was shown as deprecated and the alternative suggested was Toolbar class. I am targeting for API level>=14. Will Toolbar work for API>=14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two implementations of `Toolbar`. [One](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) is part of the Android SDK, and it is available on API Level 21+. [The other](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) is part of [the `appcompat-v7` library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), and it works on API Level 7+.